# Custom URL Per Category

Tags: category, url, url-rewrite

I'm looking for a way to server my pages by category name. So for example I have Cellphones as the category . I then want the URL to be cellphone.mystore.com. How would I make this possible?

Comment: Seems like a bad idea from a search engine / site ranking standpoint (may not apply, but worth noting).

Comment: Thanks for the comment Ben. Any reason as to why it might affect my SEO? I think it's a valid point, but just not sure of the negative effects.

Comment: "I'm no SEO expert", but your domain SEO juice is tied to the domain names. Stated simply, for a site `foo.com` with two categories and an overall SE value of 8/10, the same site split into `cat1.foo.com` and `cat2.foo.com` would effectively split the value between the two sites.

Answer (score 1):

You could **create a Website** via "System"->"Manage Stores"; "Create Website...".

When **attaching** a "Store Group" to it, you could make the category Cellphone to the `Root Category` of this group.

Be sure to set the new `Base URL` for this website only from within "System"->"Configuration"->"General"->"Web"->"Insecure".

This only works for `Root Categories` btw.

Comment: Note that site scopes add to processing and indexing overhead. If there are a lot of categories, this will become an issue.